# Add instance of a 3D component dynamically on runtime in react-three-fiber

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, react-three-fiber

I have a custom 3D object with some properties. When the app starts a instance of this object is in the canvas. At runtime I want to add another instance of the object when a button is clicked. If possible, I want to retrieve one property of the instance (the end position) so I can use it in the next instance (as a start position).

So I would like to make the following code able to add the `LinkCompo` component at runtime after a button is pushed (the button is located inside the `<SidePanel />` component, and also to use the `endLinkPos` variable ( located at `linkRef.current.children[2].position`) for the start position of the new `LinkCompo`.

The component file:

```jsx
// LinkCompo.jsx


import * as THREE from 'three';
import { forwardRef } from 'react'
import { LinkBase, LinkNext } from './Links';

const LinkCompo = forwardRef( function LinkCompo( {positionStart, linkLength}, ref) {
  const link_support_offset = 0.03;
  const cylinderHeight = linkLength - 2 * link_support_offset;
  const linkBody =  new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.025, 0.025, cylinderHeight)

  const startPos = new THREE.Vector3(positionStart[0], positionStart[1], positionStart[2]);
  const cylinderPos = new THREE.Vector3(0, cylinderHeight / 2 + link_support_offset, 0);
  const endLinkPos = new THREE.Vector3(0, linkLength, 0);

  cylinderPos.add(startPos);
  endLinkPos.add(startPos);

  return (
      <group ref={ref}>
        <LinkBase position={startPos} name="LinkA" />
        <mesh position={cylinderPos} geometry={linkBody}>
          <meshBasicMaterial color={'lime'} />
        </mesh>
        <LinkNext position={endLinkPos} name="LinkB" rotation={[0, 0, Math.PI]} />
      </group>
    )

})

export default LinkCompo;
```

The App file:

```jsx
// App.jsx

import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect  } from 'react';
import { Suspense } from 'react';
import { Stats, OrbitControls, Environment } from '@react-three/drei';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';

import SidePanel from './SidePanel';
import LinkCompo from './LinkCompo';

import './App.css';

export default function App() {

  const linkRef = useRef();
  const [links, setLinks] = useState();
  setLinks([{ 
    positionStart: [0, 0, 0] // HERE it should be -> linkRef.current.children[2].position but it is not resolved initially
    , linkLength: 0.5
  }]);
    
  useEffect(() => {
    if (linkRef.current){
      console.log(linkRef.current.children[2].position)
    }
    
  },[links])




  const handleAddLink = () => {
    
    setLinks([...links,{ 
      positionStart: [0, 0.6, 0] // HERE it should be -> linkRef.current.children[2].position but it is not resolved initially
      , linkLength: 0.5
    }]);
  };



  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="panel">
        {/* Pass handleAddLink function to SidePanel component */}
        <SidePanel onAddLink={handleAddLink} />
      </div>
      <div className="scene">
        <Canvas camera={{ position: [-0.5, 1, 2] }}>
          <Suspense fallback={null}>
            <Environment files="./environment.hdr" background blur={0.5} />
            <directionalLight position={[3.3, 1.0, 4.4]} intensity={4} />
            {links.map((link, index) => (
              <LinkCompo key={index} positionStart={link.positionStart} linkLength={link.linkLength} ref={linkRef} />
            ))}
            <OrbitControls />
            <axesHelper args={[5]} />
            <Stats />
          </Suspense>
        </Canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have tried to access the Component property with a `forwardRef()`.
It works, but not as supposed to. I use the `useEffect()` to resolve the reference but it is not called at for the initial component (maybe because the state is initialized). If I don't initialize the state, and instead use the `setLinks()` for passing the first value, error occurs (links is undefined).